# How to get cell by name with exceljs?

Tags: exceljs

For now, I have to hardcode like this

```
var cell = worksheet.getCell('A1');
```

But I want to define my cell by name like `data` and access the cell by:

```
var cell = worksheet.getCell('data');
```

[image: a busy cat]

**How can I do that with exceljs ?**
Thank you very much!

Note: The only solution seems to solve my problem is to add column/row headers and define key, but I don't want to do that in my code:

```
worksheet.columns = [
  { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 }
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in method, as far as I can tell. Here's a function that should do the trick:

```js
function getCellByName(worksheet, name) {
    var match;
    worksheet.eachRow(function (row) {
        row.eachCell(function (cell) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cell.names.length; i++) {
                if (cell.names[i] === name) {
                    match = cell;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return match;
}
```

With ES6:

```js
const getCellByName = (worksheet, name) => {
    let match
    worksheet.eachRow(row => row.eachCell(cell => {
        if (cell.names.find(n => n === name)) {
            match = cell
        }
    }))
    return match
}
```

That may end up being infeasible with very large worksheets, as you have to iterate through every non-null cell in the sheet.

If you're looking for something with that functionality built-in, I haven't tried it yet but [xlsx-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate#defined-names) looks promising.

Comment: But `xlsx-populate` only works with xlsx file, Do you know any package that works with `ods` file ?

Answer (score 9):

Just like to suggest another way.
I used console.table() to check what column-name and key in a worksheet.
I didn't have any key assign to column-name. So we iterate first row and assign cell.text to key.

```
console.table(worksheet.columns);

worksheet.getRow(1).eachCell((cell, colNumber) => {
  worksheet.getColumn(colNumber).key = cell.text;
});

console.table(worksheet.columns);


worksheet.getRow(2).getCell("UserName").value;
```